# Como puedo aumentar una variable que esta en php usando javascript y que a su vez con un boton recargue la pagina

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un programa que extrae informacion de una base de datos y quiero que cuando se le de en los botones "siguiente" Y "anterior" aumente un contador que actua como id en una consulta SQL.

```
$acum = 1;
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM noticia where Id = '$acum'";
```

Comment: Por favor comparte el código que tienes, para poder ayudarte. Así también especifica que es lo que quieres, tu variable `$acum` tiene valor inicial de **1**? Al poner siguiente, este aumenta **+1**?

Comment: Hola Nicolas, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo que completes el [tour] y que leas [ask]. También sería bueno que añadieses más detalles sobre lo que quieres, lo que llevas hasta el momento y las dificultades que te estás encontrando.

Comment: Por el título de la pregunta, parecería algo sencillo que ni siquiera requeriría JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que tengo entendido no podes manipular el contenido php desde js, ya que el código php trabaja con el servidor y js con el browser, pero podrías provar a pasarte la variable incrementada remite js con un input hidden. Para pasarte la variable a js e incrementarla podes hacer algo tipo :

```
 var acum = <?php echo $acum; ?>;
 <!-- después la convertís en int -->
 var acum2 = parseint(acum);
```

Espero que te sea útil